# How to force node position (x and y) in graphviz

Tags: position, graph-theory, graphviz, dot

I am trying to force position of nodes. I have x and y coordinates of my nodes and its also directed graph. I can use the rank=same to handle row (y coordinate), but can't figure out how I can handle column (x coordinate).

Answer (score 78):

You can use **pos** attribute (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:pos), e.g.:

```
xxx [
    label = xxx
    pos = "0,0!"
]

yyy [
    label = yyy
    pos = "10,10!"
]
```

You will also have to specify `neato` or `fdp` layout engine, so that `dot` command-line would be (for fdp):

```
dot -Kfdp -n -Tpng -o sample.png sample.dot
```

Comment: I could only get it to work by using `neato -n sample.dot ...` (not fdp)

Comment: Why the exclamation mark ? Can't find anything about it in the manual. And the behavior seems erratic (with version 2.36.0)

Comment: so, it doesn't work together with dot layout engine?

Comment: any way to only force x or y pos?

Comment: Running `dot` and overriding the layout engine is pretty confusing to people who don't know how it works and doesn't provide any benefit? The documentation specifically mentions "`-K` Specifies which default layout algorithm to use, overriding the default from the command name. For example, running dot -Kneato is equivalent to running neato."

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example I found:
https://observablehq.com/@magjac/placing-graphviz-nodes-in-fixed-positions

Essentially the position attribute "pos" can be specified for a node.  Only works with neato or fdp layout engines, not dot.

The `!` indicates that the position is an input and should not be altered.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the `-n` flag work with `dot -Kfdp`.

I was however able to get it working with neato using the following command:

`neato sample.dot -n -Tpng -o sample.png`