# How to plot connected network nodes on graph?

Tags: graph, neural-network, gnuplot

I have the location of the nodes in 2d data file which is written by my program

```
x0 = 0.12
y0 = 0.22
x1 = 0.12
y2 = 0.22 ..... 18 records for 9 node locations
```

I also have an adjacency matrix in data file which is written by my program

```
G00 = 1
G10 = 1
G70 = 0 ........81 records for 9 node locations
```

Can you guys help me plot those network nodes with connections to adjacent nodes?

Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Comment: As @Nick indicates, yes we can help, but not many of us will do it for you.

Comment: I need some guidance on how to approach this. I really don't have any expertise in this area and would really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You need to specify more things. E.g. how does your adjacency matrix look like. Also could you maybe write another format. Gnuplot is easier if you have something like:
`node0 x0 y0\n
node1 x1 y1`
where `x0,y0,x1,y1` represent the respective values

Comment: @Azrael3000 Adjacency matrix I have is also data file of 0's and 1's Gij is 1 if its a neighbor. And yes I can output with with format you specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most common ways is to use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). You'll just have to convert your adjacency matrix into a [Graphviz script](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php), which is straightforward.

Comment: I just installed Graphviz on my mac. Is there a easy quick start guide for this? That would be great to keep me started.

Comment: Check out the examples in the gallery. If you click on them. You will see the required code. Use one that resembles what you would like to achieve and modify it accordingly.

Comment: Check out the [Gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) to see what kind of code you need (Click on the picture to view the .gv file). Graphviz scripts are easy to read. Edit: seems like I fortuitously wrote exactly the same reply as Azrael3000 :)

Comment: @Azrael3000 Im kinda of confused right now :( my nodes are just points in 2d co-ordinate system like (0.2,0.3), (05.05)....

Comment: See this code: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.gv.txt
You don't specify coordinates, but links.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt coordinates are importnat information for my research. Is there anyway i can capture that information with Graphviz??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343899/how-to-force-node-position-x-and-y-in-graphviz