# How to make edges overlap in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, pygraphviz

I want to make edges overlap in graphviz. But graphviz seems to re-arrange the leaf nodes to avoid overlapping. Can I force graphviz to stop re-arranging the nodes ?

Produced:

[image: Produced]

Desired:

[image: Desired]

I am using pygraphviz to create the tree.

Comment: If you don't get answers here, you might want to try tex.stackexchange, I've seen many people doing awesome things with graphviz there.

Comment: @Pacane This is *definitely* not on-topic at TeX.SX -- it's not about TeX systems at all.  I mean, we could give you a TikZ/PSTricks/Metapost solution in a heartbeat, but Graphviz only uses LaTeX as an export format.  This is the best place to find an answer (740 tagged compared to SU's 13).  Avalokitesvara, [please do not cross-post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125191), one of the moderators can move the question for you if need be.  Even so, I think this question belongs right here.

Comment: @Sean I am sorry for the cross-posting. Let the topic stay here at stack overflow.

Comment: Related: [How to force node position (x and y) in graphviz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343899/how-to-force-node-position-x-and-y-in-graphviz)

Comment: @Sean Thanks Sean. I saw that earlier. But I use the dot layout. The Pos thing only words for neato, it doesn't work for dot :-/

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought of Tikz... My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach using **additional invisible edges** works perfectly for this graph:

```
digraph g{
  Act -> Bore;
  Act -> Cat;
  Bore -> Dog;
  Bore -> Egg [style=invis];
  Bore -> Face;
  Cat -> Egg;
  Cat -> Face [style=invis];
  Cat -> Goat;
}
```

[image: graphviz output]