# How to control ordering of root nodes?

Tags: graphviz

I can control ordering of other nodes using `ordering="in"`, but root nodes have no incoming edges to define the order by that way.

Eg:

```
digraph {
  A -> B
  C -> D
  D -> X
  B -> X
  X [ordering="in"]
}
```

It generates this:
[image: actual output]
but I want this:
[image: desired output]

Comment: please provide an example input file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question may be duplicated with [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819392/how-to-make-edges-overlap-in-graphviz).
The following approach using **additional invisible edges** works perfectly for this graph:

```
digraph {
  A -> B
  A -> D[style=invis];
  C -> B[style=invis];
  C -> D
  D -> X
  B -> X
  X [ordering="in"]
}
```

[image]