# Can't order dot - Graphviz anymore

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm using Debian Jessie. 
I've been working on dot today and I haven't been able to order anything - even using the invisible nodes trick, rank=max, rank=same, etc. 
For example, this example:

```
digraph hierarchy {

                nodesep=1.0 // increases the separation between nodes

                node [color=Red,fontname=Courier,shape=box] //All nodes will this shape and colour
                edge [color=Blue, style=dashed] //All the lines look like this

                Headteacher->{Deputy1 Deputy2 BusinessManager}
                Deputy1->{Teacher1 Teacher2}
                BusinessManager->ITManager
                {rank=same;ITManager Teacher1 Teacher2}  // Put them on the same level
}
```

from [here](http://www.tonyballantyne.com/graphs.html) just isn't ordering for me -regardless of which engine I choose, e.g., `dot -Kfdp, fdp -Kfdp, neato, etc`.

Everything starts with the Headteacher in the middle - even with

```
Headteacher [label="head teacher", rank=max]
```

Similarly, the ordering example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549477/graphviz-arranging-nodes) fails as well.

I just discovered that though my local attempts fail, eveything works as expected on [GraphvizFiddle](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/1.0.1/?1466545127784#). ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graphviz [command line reference](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html) confirms the **-K** switch to select the layout algorithm to override any inferred from the name of the command alias. If you need to use the **dot** engine, and you are not using the **dot** command, then you will need to specify this explicitly as the switch parameter.

Most of the hierarchical [attributes](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) you are specifying only apply to the hierarchical **dot** engine and have no impact otherwise. The summary identifies which engines are affected by each attribute.

Comment: From the man page, "layout=engine indicates the preferred layout engine ("dot", "neato", fdp" etc) overriding the default from the basename of the command or  the
       -K commandline option."
 It's capital K. Which I'd been using.

Comment: I don't even know what the problem was. Everything I'd read suggested I had to use fdp - not neato. fdp, twopi, neato did not work. Straight forward dot did.