# 2 components on the side in PlantUML

Tags: dot, plantuml

Here is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in PlantUML:

```
@startuml

'Define the components
[Main component] as c_main_component
[comp1] as c_comp1
[com2] as c_comp2
[comp3] as c_comp3
[comp4] as c_comp4

'Define the relationships
c_main_component -- c_comp3
c_main_component -- c_comp4

c_main_component - c_comp2
c_main_component - c_comp1

@enduml
```

The above results in the below image:

[image]

As one can see, `comp3` and `comp4` have a nice a diagonal lines connecting it to `Main component` from the bottom, just like expected. I want `comp1` and `comp2` have the same nice diagonal lines to connect to `Main component` from the right side. How can I do it?

The code as generated by PlantUML with the option `-debugsvek`:

```
digraph unix {
nodesep=0.486111;
ranksep=0.833333;
remincross=true;
searchsize=500;
sh0004->sh0006[arrowtail=none,arrowhead=none,minlen=0,color="#000011"];
sh0004->sh0005[arrowtail=none,arrowhead=none,minlen=0,color="#000015"];
sh0004 [shape=rect,label="",width=1.722222,height=0.522352,color="#000004"];
sh0005 [shape=rect,label="",width=0.861111,height=0.522352,color="#000005"];
sh0006 [shape=rect,label="",width=0.750000,height=0.522352,color="#000006"];
sh0007 [shape=rect,label="",width=0.861111,height=0.522352,color="#000007"];
sh0008 [shape=rect,label="",width=0.861111,height=0.522352,color="#000008"];
sh0004->sh0007[arrowtail=none,arrowhead=none,minlen=1,color="#000009"];
sh0004->sh0008[arrowtail=none,arrowhead=none,minlen=1,color="#00000D"];

}
```

Comment: The basic question here is actually how is it possible to define a 'docking point' i.e where the arrow between 'main component' and 'com2' should start. for this purpose I will add also the "dot" code  I was able to retrieve from plantuml (option -debugsvek) to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using for `c_comp1` and `comp2` a single dash ('-') and for `c_comp3` and `c_comp4` a double dash ('--')?

When using for all a double dash like:

```
@startuml
'Define the components
[Main component] as c_main_component
[comp1] as c_comp1
[com2] as c_comp2
[comp3] as c_comp3
[comp4] as c_comp4

'Define the relationships
c_main_component -- c_comp3
c_main_component -- c_comp4

c_main_component -- c_comp2
c_main_component -- c_comp1
@enduml
```

You will get a nicer image:

[image: corrected image]

Comment: I want `comp1` and `comp2` have the same nice diagonal lines to connect to Main component from the *right side*, not from the bottom side.

Comment: Clear to me, but I don't see a solution. I tried some things (with [hidde] and with left / right / up / down, maybe best to post also a question at http://forum.plantuml.net/questions

Answer (score 1):

I did some fiddling around and although I don't directly see it usable in this case I still think it might give some points to start.
I found this article: [How to force node position (x and y) in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343899/how-to-force-node-position-x-and-y-in-graphviz)

Based on this I modified the resulting "debugsvek file" (cc_svek.dot) to (and made some coordinates a bit different for easier calculations by head and added some labels):

```
digraph unix {
nodesep=0.5;
ranksep=1;
remincross=true;
searchsize=500;
sh0004->sh0006[arrowtail=none,arrowhead=none,minlen=0,color="#000011"];
sh0004->sh0005[arrowtail=none,arrowhead=none,minlen=0,color="#000015"];
sh0004 [pos="1,-1!",shape=rect,label="4",width=1,height=0.5,color="#000004"];
sh0005 [pos="2,-0.75!",shape=rect,label="5",width=1,height=0.5,color="#000005"];
sh0006 [pos="2,-1.25!",shape=rect,label="6",width=1,height=0.5,color="#000006"];
sh0007 [pos="0,-2!",shape=rect,label="7",width=1,height=0.5,color="#000007"];
sh0008 [pos="1,-2!",shape=rect,label="8",width=1,height=0.5,color="#000008"];
sh0004->sh0007[arrowtail=none,arrowhead=none,minlen=1,color="#000009"];
sh0004->sh0008[arrowtail=none,arrowhead=none,minlen=1,color="#00000D"];

}
```

When using the command `dot -K fdp -T png cc_svek.dot` on it this results in the image:

[image]