# Graphviz align nodes at the top/bottom horizontally

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'd like to draw a diagram like this.

[image]

I thought and searched for a long time and I can only generate the picture below.

[image]

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=plaintext]
//    newrank=true;

    subgraph part1 {
        {rank=same state0, state9, state6}
        subgraph nest1 {
            state0 [label=<
                    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                    <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">0</TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD PORT="text1" bgcolor="red">S&rarr; ・E$</TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD PORT="text2" bgcolor="green">E&rarr; ・E+T <br/> E&rarr;・T </TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD PORT="text3" bgcolor="green">T&rarr; ・id <br/> T&rarr;・(E)</TD></TR>
                    </TABLE>>];
        }

        subgraph nest2 {
            state6 [label=<
                    <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                    <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">6</TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD PORT="text1" bgcolor="red">T&rarr;(・E) </TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD PORT="text2" bgcolor="green">E&rarr; ・E+T <br/> E&rarr;・T </TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD PORT="text3" bgcolor="green">T&rarr; ・id <br/> T&rarr;・(E)</TD></TR>
                    </TABLE>>];
        }

        subgraph nest3 {
            state9 [label=<
                    <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                    <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">9</TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">E&rarr;T・ </TD></TR>
                    </TABLE>>];

            state5 [label=<
                    <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                    <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">5</TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">T&rarr;id・ </TD></TR>
                    </TABLE>>];
        }

//        {rank=same; nest1; nest2; nest3;}
//        nest1 -> nest2 -> nest3 [style=invis]
    }

    subgraph part2 {
        {rank=same state1, state3, state7}
        state1 [label=<
                <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">1</TD></TR>
                <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">S&rarr;E・$<br/>E&rarr;E・+T</TD></TR>
                </TABLE>>];

        state7 [label=<
                <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">7</TD></TR>
                <TR><TD PORT="text1" bgcolor="red">T&rarr;(E・) </TD></TR>
                <TR><TD PORT="text2" bgcolor="green">E&rarr; E・+T</TD></TR>
                </TABLE>>];

        state3 [label=<
                <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">3</TD></TR>
                <TR><TD PORT="text1" bgcolor="red">E&rarr;E+・T </TD></TR>
                <TR><TD PORT="text2" bgcolor="green">T&rarr;・id <br/> T&rarr;・(E) </TD></TR>
                </TABLE>>];
    }

    subgraph part3 {
        {rank=same state2, state4, state8}

        state2 [label=<
                <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">2</TD></TR>
                <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">S&rarr;E$・ </TD></TR>
                </TABLE>>];

        state8 [label=<
                <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">8</TD></TR>
                <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">T&rarr;(E)・ </TD></TR>
                </TABLE>>];

        state4 [label=<
                <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">4</TD></TR>
                <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">E&rarr;E+T・ </TD></TR>
                </TABLE>>];
    }

//    state0:s -> state1:n [label="E"]
//    state0:title:e -> state9:title:w [label="T"]
//    state0:text3:e -> state5:text:w [label="id"]
//    state0:text2:e -> state6:text2:w [label="("]

    state0:s -> state1:n [label="E"]
    state0 -> state9 [label="T"]
    state0 -> state5 [label="id"]
    state0 -> state6 [label="(", weight=100]

    state1:s -> state2:n [label="$"]
    state1:title:e -> state3:title:w [label="+"]

    state3:s -> state4:n [label="T"]
    state3:n -> state5:s [label="id"]
//    state3:title:e -> state6:s [label="("]
    state3:title:e -> state6 [label="("]

//    state6:text3:w -> state5:text:e [label="id"]
//    state6:s -> state7:n [label="E"]
//    state6:title:w -> state9:title:e [label="T"]
//    state6:title:n -> state6:e [label="("]

    state6:s -> state7:n [label="E"]
    state6 -> state9 [label="T"]
    state6 -> state5 [label="id"]
    state6 -> state6 [label="("]

    state7:text2:w -> state3:text2:e [label="+"]
    state7:s -> state8:n [label=")"]

    // ------------ Invisible edges to order vertically node groups
    state9:s -> state5:n [style=invis]
    state5:s -> state3:n [style=invis]
    state3:s -> state4:n [style=invis]

    state6:s -> state7:n [style=invis]
    state7:s -> state8:n [style=invis]
    // ---------------------------------------------------

    // below two lines make sure the order 1 3 7 | 2 4 8 is right
    state1 -> state3 -> state7 [style=invis]
    state2 -> state4 -> state8 [style=invis]

    state0:text1:e -> state9:text1:w [style=invis]
    state9:text1:e -> state6:text1:w [style=invis]
}
```

I want to adjust the 0 9 5 6 part. This means I need to rank same 0 9/5 6, I have tried using subgraph, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Is there any way to align two nodes horizontally and keep them top/bottom align like HTML image?

[image]

---

tk421 memtions `neato` in his answer, see [How to force node position (x and y) in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343899) for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple fixes you can apply.  `splines=ortho` will change the edges to vertical and horizontal lines.  When you do this, the edge labels have to be redone as `xlabel=` instead of `label=`.

[image]

However, the 9 and 5 are not placed properly.  If you use `neato` instead
of `dot`, you can position the nodes exactly where you want.  Then you can
remove all the subgraph and invisible nodes and weight and do this:

[image]

The graphviz code would be:

```
digraph G {
    splines=ortho;
    node [shape=plaintext]

    state0 [label=<
            <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">0</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text1" bgcolor="red">S&rarr; ・E$</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text2" bgcolor="green">E&rarr; ・E+T <br/> E&rarr;・T </TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text3" bgcolor="green">T&rarr; ・id <br/> T&rarr;・(E)</TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="0,4!"];

    state6 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">6</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text1" bgcolor="red">T&rarr;(・E) </TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text2" bgcolor="green">E&rarr; ・E+T <br/> E&rarr;・T </TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text3" bgcolor="green">T&rarr; ・id <br/> T&rarr;・(E)</TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="4,4!"];

    state9 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">9</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">E&rarr;T・ </TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="2,4.7!"];

    state5 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">5</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">T&rarr;id・ </TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="2,3.3!"];

    state1 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">1</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">S&rarr;E・$<br/>E&rarr;E・+T</TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="0,1.5!"];

    state7 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">7</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text1" bgcolor="red">T&rarr;(E・) </TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text2" bgcolor="green">E&rarr; E・+T</TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="4,1.5!"];

    state3 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">3</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text1" bgcolor="red">E&rarr;E+・T </TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text2" bgcolor="green">T&rarr;・id <br/> T&rarr;・(E) </TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="2,1.5!"];

    state2 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">2</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">S&rarr;E$・ </TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="0,0!"];

    state8 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">8</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">T&rarr;(E)・ </TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="4,0!"];

    state4 [label=<
            <TABLE ALIGN="LEFT" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="yellow">4</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="red">E&rarr;E+T・ </TD></TR>
            </TABLE>>, pos="2,0!"];

    state0:s -> state1:n [xlabel="E"]
    state0 -> state9 [xlabel="T"]
    state0:e -> state5:w [xlabel="id"]
    state0 -> state6 [xlabel="("]

    state1:s -> state2:n [xlabel="$"]
    state1:title:e -> state3:title:w [xlabel="+"]

    state3:s -> state4:n [xlabel="T"]
    state3:n -> state5:s [xlabel="id"]
    state3:title:e -> state6 [xlabel="("]

    state6:s -> state7:n [xlabel="E"]
    state6 -> state9 [xlabel="T"]
    state6 -> state5 [xlabel="id"]
    state6 -> state6 [xlabel="("]

    state7:text2:w -> state3:text2:e [xlabel="+"]
    state7:s -> state8:n [xlabel=")"]
}
```

#### References

- [Node, Edge and Graph Attributes:Splines](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:splines)
- [Node, Edge and Graph Attributes:pos](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:pos)
- [Placing Graphviz nodes in fixed positions](https://observablehq.com/@magjac/placing-graphviz-nodes-in-fixed-positions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your answer makes the line straight. But what I really want is to rank state0 (state9 state5) state6 same like the first picture I gave. What your solution and my solution's realization only rank state0 state9 and state6 same.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I have a question that is there any way to control how to draw the self-connection line in state 6? The default style of self-connection is from top to bottom, but I'd like to use port like `from N to NE` or `from E to NE` to reduce the space the self-connection line takes up. But port doesn't work in this case. I think I can use invisible node to do that, but that's a lot typing. I searched a lot in Google, it didn't help me. Is there any simplier way to do that?

Comment: I played around with it too and couldn't find anything that works.  My guess is that the rendering engine has problems with embedded HTML.