# is there a way to specify which node goes above another in pythons diagrams?

Tags: python, graphviz, diagram

I'm using diagrams and trying to force a node to go on top of another:

```py
with Diagram("My Diagram", show=False):
    A = ELB("A")
    B = EC2("B")
    C = RDS("C")

    A >> B
    A >> C
```

Which renders:

[image]

Is there a way to enforce node `C` going above node `B`?

Of course, in this simple example, simply changing the name/order of B and C could do the trick, but this doesn't work when the graph is more complex.

Comment: Since diagrams uses graphviz internally, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343899/how-to-force-node-position-x-and-y-in-graphviz) will help? Not sure how to apply that to diagrams.